# Neo4j expand array elements into separate rows

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I have a CSV file that has columns that contain arrays. The file looks like this:

```
siblings
[3010,3011,3012]
[2010,2012]
```

What I am trying to do is to return the elements of the arrays as separate rows.

I looked through the documentation and found `UNWIND` function. When I tried the example shown in the documentation:

```
UNWIND [1, 2, 3] AS x
RETURN x
```

everything worked fine. When I tried it with my data the query looked like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///test.csv' AS line1
UNWIND line1.siblings as a
RETURN a
```

and the result was

```
[3010,3011,3012]
[2010,2012]
```

instead of:

```
3010
3011
3012
...
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSV columns are all handled as strings so you need to treat them as such. In your case you can remove the brackets from the *siblings*  column prior to splitting the string into a collection.  That step would help you to avoid pre-processing the file. Once you split the string then you still have a collection of strings.

```
WITH "[1001,1002,1003]" as numbers_with_brackets_in_a_string
WITH substring( numbers_with_brackets_in_a_string, 1, size(numbers_with_brackets_in_a_string)-2 ) as numbers_in_a_string
UNWIND split( numbers_in_a_string, ',' ) as number_as_a_string
RETURN number_as_a_string
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found an ugly way of fixing this.

I did the following thing:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///test.csv' AS line1
WITH line1, split(line1.siblings, ",") as s
UNWIND s as sib
RETURN sib
```

after which I got the following thing:

```
[3010
3011
3012]
...
```

I removed `[]` from the CSV file and I got the output that I desired.

I know this is an ugly solutions and I would appreciate if someone could find a better one.